# Selenium returns an empty list from XPath of span elements

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape some web elements by inspecting the webpage and identifying the XPath of what I want to extract. For some elements, I get the intended result for others I do not. See below the replicable example:

Uploading the page I want to analyse:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.get("https://medium.com/search")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys("international development",Keys.ENTER)
```

Then, I identify the path of the elements I want to see using XPath language:

```
article_2016_t_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"postArticle--short")][.//time[contains(@datetime, "2016")]][//span[@class="readingTime"]]'
article_element_list_t_1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(article_2016_t_xpath)
```

To extract the values I wish, I am now looking for the elements time and span in the article list. The end result is a list of timelines but also an empty list of reading times. I tried to use different versions instead of `article.find_element_by_tag_name` such as `[article.text for node in WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='readingTime']")))]` without reaching the intended results

```
lista =[]
timelines=[]    
for article in article_element_list_t_1:
    readingtime = article.find_element_by_tag_name("span").text
    Timelines = article.find_element_by_tag_name("time").text
    timelines.append(Timelines)
    lista.append(readingtime)  
lista
```

I am wondering 1) how to get the reading time of each article hosted in the span of the webpage but also 2) why time shows as a text and span does not. What are the key criteria/references to consider when calling elements by tag_name from a XPath depending on where they are located within the main div wrapper?

Comment: Was your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** You use wrong types of selectors for sub-elements.

**2** You do not use any waits, so your page is not completely loaded.

#### Solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get("https://medium.com/search")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys("international development", Keys.ENTER)

article_2016_t_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,"postArticle--short")][.//time[contains(@datetime, "2016")]][//span[@class="readingTime"]]'
article_element_list_t_1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(article_2016_t_xpath)

lista = []
timelines = []
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.readingTime')))
for article in article_element_list_t_1:
    readingtime = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'readingTime')]").get_attribute("title")
    Timelines = article.find_element_by_xpath(".//time").text
    timelines.append(Timelines)
    lista.append(readingtime)

for i in lista:
    print(i)
for i in timelines:
    print(i)

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

`readingtime` is not text, it's attribute `title`.
`Timelines` is text, but you need to use xpath here.
Also, I've added nice explicit wait by CSS. `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.readingTime')))`

#### Output

```
8 min read
5 min read
3 min read
4 min read
6 min read
3 min read
5 min read
Feb 29, 2016
Sep 5, 2016
Mar 30, 2016
Jan 13, 2016
May 25, 2016
Aug 4, 2016
Mar 21, 2016
```

Comment: I'm on Linux, change your path in accordance to your Windows paramaters.